# Conversion between VB.net TO C# (new EventHandler) NO overload matches delegate

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am new to C# and I need to convert my code from VB.NET to C#.

Here is my VB.NET code

```vb
Private Sub Receive()
    Dim inp As NetworkStream
    Dim income As BinaryReader
    inp = TCP.GetStream
    income = New BinaryReader(inp)

    While (State = "Connected")
        Try
            msg = income.ReadChar
            Application.OpenForms(0).Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf prin))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Try
                Me.Det = False
                If TCpThread.IsAlive = True Then TCpThread.Abort()
                TCP.Close()
                msg = ex.Message
            Catch ex1 As Exception
                Application.OpenForms(0).Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf prin))
            End Try
            State = "IDLE"
        End Try
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub prin()
    Message &= msg
    Check(Message)
End Sub
```

It works fine, I converted it to:

```
private void Receive()
{
    NetworkStream inp = default(NetworkStream);
    BinaryReader income = default(BinaryReader);
    inp = TCP.GetStream();
    income = new BinaryReader(inp);

    while (State == "Connected")
    {
        try
        {
            msg = System.Convert.ToString(income.ReadChar());
            Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke(new EventHandler(prin));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Det = false;
                if (TCpThread.IsAlive == true)
                {
                    TCpThread.Abort();
                }
                TCP.Close();
                msg = ex.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke(new EventHandler(prin));
            }
            State = "IDLE";
        }
    }
}

private void prin()
{
    Message += msg;
    Check(Message);
}
```

But I get

> Error  1   No overload for 'prin' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

for this line `Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke(new EventHandler(prin));`. Based on the multi-threading I need to invoke a function in order to follow my thread while it is running.

what is my mistake?

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: Prin() needs to match the signature of a System.EventHandler delegate.   `private void prin(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: VB.NET is forgiving when getting the Sub declaration wrong, it can make it work so it does, but that's not the C# way.  Watch out for this, you'll surely encounter it elsewhere.

Comment: If you want to convert VB code to C#, I would strongly recommend starting by turning `Option Strict On` in your VB code.  The resulting VB dialect is a lot closer to C# in terms of what needs to be specified explicitly vs. what the compiler will try to paper over with a best guess of what you were trying to do.

Comment: (It should also be noted that there are consequences to non-`Strict` VB's acceptance of not-exactly-matching declarations that can cause subtle bugs later.  I've been bitten by it before.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke(new Action(prin));
```

The type `EventHandler` represents a delegate with two parameters (a generic `object` and an `EventArgs` object). Your method `prin` doesn't match that description.

If you just want to create a delegate for your method, use a delegate type that has the same arguments as your method (in this case none). In this case, this is the `Action` delegate.

The Action delegate should also have been used in the VB code in the first place:

```
Application.OpenForms(0).Invoke(New Action(AddressOf prin))
```

However, using `EventHandler` works in VB because the `AddressOf` operator in VB is not really type safe.

Comment: "the AddressOf operator in VB is not really type safe" is an overstatement - in the end the compiler does generate the exact delegate type required. `AddressOf` isn't a free-for-all, for all the "forgiving" it may allow. However, there are two avenues of "surprises" and I can think of: (1) run-time errors from narrowing conversions (which may be avoidable via `Option Strict On`); (2) whatever consequences there may be in using default values for any remaining unmatched parameters of the delegate type.

Comment: Anyway the compiler does validate types between respective parameters of delegate and `AddressOf` (per the degree of implicit conversion allowed) while compiling. For anyone interested, the particulars on what it does and will allow are in section "Delegate-Creation Expressions" at https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some VB.NET code to C# conversions. Some work, some don't

```vb
Invoke(AddressOf prin) ' doesn't compile
Invoke(Sub() prin())
Invoke(New Action(AddressOf prin))
Invoke(New NoParameterVoid(AddressOf prin))
Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf prin)) ' doesn't compile with Option Strict On (original code)
' ...
Delegate Sub NoParameterVoid() ' required for 4th item
```

```
Invoke(prin); // doesn't compile
Invoke(() => prin()); // doesn't compile
Invoke(new Action(prin));
Invoke(new NoParameterVoid(prin));
Invoke(new EventHandler(prin)); // doesn't compile
// ...
delegate void NoParameterVoid(); // required for 4th item
```

So the only two which are directly convertible to C# code which compiles are

```vb
Invoke(New Action(AddressOf prin))
Invoke(New NoParameterVoid(AddressOf prin))
```

and since the `Delegate Sub NoParameterVoid()` we need to create is identical to `Action()`, there's no point in creating it, in my opinion. So the only reasonable option, when trying to convert directly to c#, is:

```vb
Invoke(New Action(AddressOf prin))
```

```
Invoke(new Action(prin));
```

This might not have been a question if you had `Option Strict On` to begin with; you may have come up with `Action()` on your own.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation and your help.